# java json github-api git github pull-request loops get jsonpath parsing resttemplate spring spring-boot

Tags: java, json, github-api, pull-request, jsonpath

I got a `json` String from request of `github api (/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls).`
Then I `parsed` it into a `DocumentContext` using `JsonPath.parse(json).`

Now I want to iterate over my `DocumentContext` using the `read(path)` function, but the `github api` does not have a size/length or amount of pull-requests.

```java
String json = https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
DocumentContext dc = JsonPath.parse(json)

for (int i = 0; i < dc.read($.somethingLikeSize); i++){
  //get the objects
  private int id = dc.read($.[i]...);
  //...
}
```

As I guess, the open_issues_count or open_issues can be pull-requests, but they don't have to.

How can I iterate over my `documentContext.read($.[i]...) without getting a PathNotFoundException` ?

(PS: Please be gentle, I'm a newbie.)

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "...";
DocumentContext dc = JsonPath.parse(json);
List<String> listOfValues = dc.read("$.[?].key");
```

then you can iterate over `listOfValues`

Comment: I can already iterate over `dc` and get the `$.[?].values` but I can't get the length or size of `?` (in my case there are two open pull-requests but imagine there could be another amount).

Comment: I think you can't get the size of `?` but you can get the size of that list using function `size()`, which is actually the size of `?`.
usage: `listOfValues.size();`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it kinda solved my problem, I had just to read specific pull-request keys into a new list and get the `size()`.